# Como fazer Redirect na página com Django

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django

Como fazer redirect passando um objeto como parametro no django já tentei 
`redirect()` e `HttpResponseRedirect` mas não consigo enviar um objeto para página no response, toda vez que aperto f5 ele quer reenviar a requisição. Como
resolver esse problema ?

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from webapp.metodos.gauss import Gauss
from django.urls import reverse


import numpy as np
import csv
import io


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        matriz = readCSV(request)
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'matriz': matriz})
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def gauss(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        g = Gauss()
        matriz = readCSV(request)
        resultado = g.executar(matriz)  
        return render(request, 'gauss.html', {'resultado': resultado})
    return render(request, 'gauss.html')


def gaussjordan(request):
    return render(request, 'gaussjordan.html')


def fatoracaolu(request):
    return render(request, 'fatoracaolu.html')


def readCSV(request):
    data = request.FILES['file'].read().decode('UTF-8')
    io_string = io.StringIO(data)
    matriz = np.loadtxt(io_string, delimiter=',', dtype=int)
    return matriz



    <form class="form-group" action="{% url 'index' %}" method="POST" 
                   enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {{ form.file }}
                        {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Executar">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="arquivo" required />
    <form>
```

Comment: Você está querendo redirecionar para uma pagina após o submit de um form? Poderia postar o código completo da view?

Comment: correto quero redirecionar passando um objeto que vai ser carregado na pagina alterei código coloquei form

Comment: Coloque o código da view, onde você processa o form, todo o código se possível, porquê creio que utilizar um CCBV será melhor, mas para dizer como fazer, precisarei ver a view.

Comment: coloquei toda código da view e form no html

Answer (score 0):

Tente alterar o render do Return do seu if para Redirect.
Ex:

```
def gauss(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        g = Gauss()
        matriz = readCSV(request)
        resultado = g.executar(matriz)  
        return redirect('gauss')
    return render(request, 'gauss.html')
```

Comment: editado Fernando, erro de bios rs

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente seu problema é a estrutura de *views* que você está pensando.
Seria muito mais simples você passar `resultado` ou `None` para o template, e no template você mostra o resultado apenas se ele existir. Exemplo:

```
def gauss(request):
    resultado = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        g = Gauss()
        matriz = readCSV(request)
        resultado = g.executar(matriz)  

    return render(request, 'gauss.html',  {'resultado': resultado})
```

---

Já para redirecionar o usuário para outra URL no Django você deve retornar um objeto do tipo [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) passando uma URL para o construtor.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect("https://pt.stackoverflow.com/")
    # ou
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/minha-pagina/")
    # ou
    return HttpResponseRedirect("minha-pagina/relativa")
```

Mas essa não é maneira mais comum de se fazer o redirecionamento, geralmente se usa uma função utilitária disponibilizada pelo próprio Django, seria a função [`django.shortcuts.redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

Ela é mais comumente utilizada pois ela trata de montar a URL automaticamente para você, basta que você passe:

1. Um model que implemente o método [`get_absolute_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url):

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import redirect

   def my_view(request):
       ...
       obj = MyModel.objects.get(...)
       return redirect(obj)
   ```

   <sup>*Se você verificar o [código fonte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/shortcuts/#redirect) verá que basta ser qualquer objeto que tenha um atributo invocável chamado `get_absolute_url`, não sendo obrigatório ser um Model.*</sup>
2. Uma string representando uma *view* (você pode passar os argumentos para a view assim como você faz quando usa [`django.urls.reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse)):

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import redirect

   def my_view(request):
       ...
       return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
   ```
3. Passar uma string que representa um URL (mesmo comportamento de quando você usa [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect))

   ```
   from django.shortcuts import redirect

   def my_view(request):
       ...
       return redirect('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/')
   ```

Para entender melhor, você pode (e deve) verificar o [código da função `django.shortcut.redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/shortcuts/#redirect), você verá que ela não faz muito mais do que chamar a função `resolve_url`. O código da função `resolve_url` é curto e se encontra mais abaixo de `redirect` no mesmo arquivo.